# Palindrome tester using stack and queue application problem in Java

Tags: java, palindrome

I created an application to test if the given input string is a palindrome.
But this program doesn't detect a real palindrome, and only returns false whenever.
I really couldn't figure out why the method doesn't work.
Could anyone give me a piece of advice?
Thanks.

```
public boolean palindromeTest()
{   
    // checks if the top of stack and the head of queue is the same for all elements
    // if not, breaks the while loop and returns false
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        if (stack.peek() != queue.first())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            queue.dequeue();
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong

```
if (stack.peek() != queue.first())
```

You are trying to compare two strings. However, your code only checks whether the strings are the *same object*.

```
if (!stack.peek().equals(queue.first()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a string with `!=` does not work in Java.  `!=` checks if both objects compared are actually the same object. So you need to check using `equals`:

```
if (!stack.peek().equals(queue.first()))
```

Apart from that, this seems like a very convoluted way of checking if a string is a palindrome. Basically a palindrome is a word that which reads the same backward as forward. So you can easily solve this problem by just reversing the input string and compare the reversed input string to the original input string.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //initiates a user input string 
    System.out.println("Enter a string to check: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String palin = input.nextLine();

    //removes blank spaces in the input string
    palin = palin.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    // reverse the string
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(palin).reverse().toString();

    if (palin.equals(reverse)) { 
        System.out.println("Given string is a palindrome."); 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Given string is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I agree. it's the condition of the assignment so.. anyway Thanks for your help :)!